# Changing the root directory (/) of git bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, msys2

Is there a way to change the root (/) directory of git bash on windows.

By default it is set to the installation folder. Setting it to c:\ instead would save needing to type the drive letter e.g. /c/some/path on all absolute paths.

Comment: Even if this was possible it would make  both `"C:\D\"` and `"D:\"` correspond to same `/D/`

Comment: It could perhaps add a mount 'drives', so you could do /drives/d. In android its /storage/sdcard0, etc. Which gives the root as / but also access to other drives.

Answer (score 14):

`echo 'cd /c/' >> ~/.bashrc`

Automatically go to /c/ directory when opening bash cli.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I upvoted it.  It works great for me and is *way* better than copying folders into the root C: drive like the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: If it helps your use case it's great, I wouldn't downvote it. However it doesn't allow unix style absolute paths for the c drive, so can't accept it as the answer either.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is mount some windows paths to a root-based msys2 paths:

`mount c:/src /src`

Then you can access C:/src/... as /src/...

Comment: This is a good workaround, it's limited to mapping individual directories in Cygwin, but something that works in git bash for all directories might not be possible.

Comment: Right, mounting to root does not work. But I did not propose it.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed git right, then two commands will appear in the file explorer menu when you call it with right-click. You will see nice color-full icons for both two commands:
- Git GUI Here 
- Git bash Here
took me 3 days... so you can run both from anywhere.. just go there and run from there!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (Windows 10) was to edit the shortcut.

Previously the Target was "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home
Start in: was my homedir

I changed Start in to be C: and removed --cd-to-home

Now bash starts in /c

Answer (score 1):

In your `.bashrc` file :

```sh
function cd {
  cd "/c/${1}"
}
```

I would think this should work for all cases. This *would* limit you to C Drive absolute paths though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by searching the `bash.rc` file in my file explorer, opening the file with code and replacing everything with `cd /C:\Users\windows/`